# 14.04 - gnome terminal missing after installing virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu having switched over from Windows. I was playing around with Oracle Virtualbox but after I installed it there were a few problems when I rebooted my laptop. The unity launcher and dash had disappeared and the ctrl+alt+t doesn't bring up the default terminal but something called XTerm instead.

I managed to fix the missing launcher/dash but I'm still having issues with the terminal. It doesn't even show up when I try to run a search for it. Any help with this problem would be much appreciated!

Also, I've since uninstalled virtualbox.

Comment: Does the package itself show up if you do `dpkg -l gnome-terminal` (in the `xterm`)? What about `update-alternatives --list x-terminal-emulator`?

Comment: @steeldriver The first command brings up Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge and the second lists paths to what looks like xterm variants? There's koi8rxterm, uxterm, lxterm and then just xterm

Comment: I actually think I somehow managed to totally uninstall it. sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal has brought it back :)

Comment: @user2463465 - in that case add it as the answer below :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after running the two commands that @steeldriver suggested, I realised that I'd somehow managed to totally uninstall the gnome terminal from my laptop.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've also lost the installed terminator and console on my ubuntu 14.04 after installed virtual box. The Ctrl + Alt + t helped me to open the default console and reinstall the gnome-terminal